# In PHP is there a better way to do dynamic templating

Tags: php, regex, str-replace, explode, templating

I'm creating module for an application which will have simple custom templating with tags that will be replaced with data from a database. The field names will be different in each instance of this module. I want to know if there is a better way to do this.

The code below is what I've come up with, But I believe there must be a better way. I struggled with preg_split and preg_match_all and just hit my limit so I did it the dumb person way.

```
<?php

$customTemplate = "
<div>
    <<This>>
    <<that>>
</div>
";

function process_template ($template, $begin = '<<', $end = '>>') {
    $begin_exploded = explode($begin, $template);
    if (is_array($begin_exploded)) {
        foreach ($begin_exploded as $key1 => $value1) {
            $end_exploded = explode($end, $value1);

            if (is_array($end_exploded)) {
                foreach ($end_exploded as $key2 => $value2) {
                    $tag = $begin.$value2.$end;
                    $variable = trim($value2);

                    $find_it = strpos($template,$tag);
                    if ($find_it !== false) {
                        //str_replace ($tag, $MyClass->get($variable), $template );
                        $template = str_replace ($tag, $variable, $template);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $template;
}


echo(process_template($customTemplate));

/* Will Echo 

<div>
    This
    that
</div>

*/
?>
```

In the future I will connect $MyClass->get() to replace the tag with the proper data. And the custom template will be built by the user.

Comment: there are php templating engines,  you don't have to write your own,

Comment: Not to mention, php *is* itself a simple templating language. If you’re separating logic from your view, about all that is left is looping and printing variables. Your view could (should?) be all html with only the php being one-liners such as `<?php while($row=$someObj->nextRow(): ?>` and `<li><?= $row->varName ?></li>`

Comment: https://twig.symfony.com/ or https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade. Have at 'em.

Comment: Note that `explode()` returns always an array, the two `is_array()` tests are not needed.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Thanks, makes sense.

Comment: @ceejayoz I plan to look into them. Thanks

Comment: @tim Thanks, maybe I'll use them in a future project.

Comment: @TimMorton I didn't want the user to have to know anything about php to add variables to a template, just simple recognizable tags. Thank you for your input. I'll think about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than `preg_split` or `preg_match` I would rather use `preg_replace_callback`, since you are doing replacements, and the replacement value is derived from what looks like will end up being a method in another class.

```
function process_template($template, $begin = '<<', $end = '>>') {
    // get $MyClass in the function scope somehow. Maybe pass it as another parameter?
    return preg_replace_callback("/$begin(\w+)$end/", function($var) use ($MyClass) {
        return $MyClass->get($var[1]);
    }, $template);
}
```

Here's an example to play with: https://3v4l.org/N1p03

I assume this is just for fun/learning. If I really needed to use a template for something I would rather start with `composer require "twig/twig:^2.0"` instead. In fact, if you're interested in learning more about how it works you could go check out a well-established system like twig or blade does it. ([Better than I've done it in this answer.](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/internals.html))

Comment: No, this isn't just for fun/learning. I would like to learn twig and laravel and every other framework. But I'm a budget developer working on a budget wordpress beaver builder custom module.

Comment: Thanks, This looks like it will turn out to be the better way to handle it once my logic is finished. Thank you Sir!

Answer (score 0):

There are tons templating engines around, but sometimes... just add complexity and dependencies for a maybe simple thing. This a modified sample of what I used for make some javascript corrections. This works for your template.

```php
function process_template($html,$b='<<',$e='>>'){
    $replace=['this'=>'<input name="this" />','that'=>'<input name="that" />'];
    if(preg_match_all('/('.$b.')(.*?)('.$e.')/is',$html,$matches,PREG_SET_ORDER|PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE)){
      $t='';$o=0;
      foreach($matches as $m){
        //for reference $m[1][0] contains $b, $m[2][0] contains $e
        $t.=substr($html,$o,$m[0][1]-$o);
        $t.=$replace[$m[2][0]];
        $o=$m[3][1]+strlen($m[3][0]);
      }
      $t.=substr($html,$o);
      $html=$t;
    }
    return $html;
}
$html="
<div>
    <<this>>
    <<that>>
</div>
";
$new=process_template($html);
echo $new;
```

For demo purpose I put the array `$replace` that handling the substitutions. You replace those with your function that will handle the replacement.

Here is a working snippet: https://3v4l.org/MBnbR

I like this function because you have control of what to replace and what to put back on the final result. By the way by using the `PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE` also return on the matches the position where the regexp groups happens. Those are on the `$m[x][1]`. The captured text will be on `$m[x][0]`.

Comment: "just add complexity and dependencies for a maybe simple thing" Folks tend to find out that this "complexity and dependencies" actually winds up being "widely used, well tested code where the edge cases have already been discovered and addressed". https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reinventing_the_wheel

Comment: Thanks for understanding. I do want to learn these other frameworks. Until I learn them I really don't know how much time and complexity it would add to this small project. 

Thanks I appreciate your solution!

Comment: @ceejayoz I agree with you that I should be more carefully about that statement, specially for somebody who is learning it's way. I have more of 30 years of coding experience and my current role is all about code optimization without getting cut on the bare metal. But also I have seen junior coders going in the horror dependency rabbit hole. It's not about reinventing the wheel, it's about adding more wheels of what you need.  Zrux, I will recommend not just learn how to use a framework, also eventually learn how it works.